# Error: asp.net MVC-5 model item to IEnumerable

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working with .NET MVC-5. And I'm getting the above error.
In my case I have a controller named as "Customer-controller". Which consists of two **Action Results** named as **"Index"** and **"Details".**

Index is rendering a list of customers from database. The question is if I click on any of name in the list of customers (rendered by "Index") should redirect me to details action Result and show the details related to specific customer.

**Customer Controller**

```
public class CustomerController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public CustomerController()
    {
        _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        _context.Dispose();

    }
    // GET: Customer
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var customers = _context.Customers.ToList();
        return View(customers);
    }

    public ActionResult Details(int  id)
    {
        var cus = _context.Customers.FirstOrDefault(c=> c.Id==id);
        if (cus == null)
            return  HttpNotFound();
        return View(cus);

    }
}
```

**Index cshtml**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-hover">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Customer Name</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

@foreach (var i in Model)
{
    <tr>

        <td>@Html.ActionLink(@i.Name, "Details", "Customer", new {id=1 }, null)</td>
    </tr>
}

</tbody>
```

**Detail cshtml**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Customer Id</th>
    <th>Customer Name</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

@foreach (var i in Model)
{ 
    <tr>
        <td> @i.Id @i.Name </td>
    </tr>
}


</tbody>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are selecting data using `FirstOrDefault`, so it will return single entity object of `Customers` class and you are trying to iterate it, which is wrong.

here, you can resolve it using **2 ways**.

**1)** Here you will get object value without `foreach` like below.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Customer Id</th>
    <th>Customer Name</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

    <tr>
        <td> @i.Id @i.Name </td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
```

**2)** If you do not want to change View code, then you need to pass `list` object from controller like below.

```
public ActionResult Details(int  id)
{
   var cus = _context.Customers.FirstOrDefault(c=> c.Id==id);
   List<Customers> lstcus =  new List<Customers>();
   lstcus.Add(cus);

   if (cus == null)
        return  HttpNotFound();

   return View(lstcus);

}
```

Comment: both will work, but you should definitely consider using option 1

Comment: Thanks for your effort. But I still have a question. Suppose. I use way-1 you have mentioned above. 
How can I get name and Id of customer in view?? in my case as i did @i.Id. But it gives error if i remove foreach loop